# Can smb explain why this is **true**

Tags: prolog, logic

Can smb explain why this is **true**?

```
not(G).
not(G) :- G, !, fail.
```

Comment: see [negation by failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure)

Comment: Prolog finds anything to be *true* as long as it can find something in it's KB to match with. So not(*anything*) is true to Prolog because not(G) is true, and G can be *anything*

Comment: @false 'smb' is a very lazy man's 'somebody'

Comment: @Kemal P. to extend on Ruben's and repeat's answers: prolog will try to reach your goal by trying the predicates in your base *in order*. (In fact, this 'default selection function' is part of what makes the language). If you reverse the order of your predicates, you get a working `not`

Comment: @Ruben `true` would have been clearer named `proved`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true because the first clause reads:

```
not(_).
```

The code you got there is weird. The name `not` does not quite fit its obvious declarative meaning.